# i have issue for deploying app on heroku Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mysql-client==2.0.1

Tags: python, flask

I am posting my traceback

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mysql-client==2.0.1 (from -r /tmp/build_632f17b9/requirements.txt (line 83)) (from versions: none)
remote:        ERROR: No matching distribution found for mysql-client==2.0.1 (from -r /tmp/build_632f17b9/requirements.txt (line 83))
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
```

Comment: Where are you expecting that package to come from? Looking at PyPI, there's only a 0.0.1: https://pypi.org/project/mysql-client/#history